# How to query MS Graph properly from Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular app (SPA) that consumes .net core webapi app (back-end) and I want to implement single sign on properly using MSAL-Angular auth_code flow + PKCE support.

I have looked it up and I found a [Typescript implementation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/TypescriptTestApp2.0) which can be used in my angular app as a service that can be called in any module/component

All I had to install from npm is `@azure/msal-browser` (supports PCKE)

and then I have created the following in my Angular app folder:

**graph-config.ts**
this file has all my MS Graph end-points that I am going to use in my app

```
export const GRAPH_CONFIG = {
    GRAPH_ME_ENDPT: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    GRAPH_ME_GROUPS: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true"
};
```

**user-info.ts**
This is just a class to hold the graph data about the logged in user

```
export class UserInfo {
  businessPhones?: Array<string>;
  displayName?: string;
  givenName?: string;
  id?: string;
  jobTitle?: string;
  mail?: string;
  mobilePhone?: string;
  officeLocation?: string;
  preferredLanguage?: string;
  surname?: string;
  userPrincipalName?: string;
}
```

I have also defined 2 services..
**First Service: msal-auth.service.ts**

This is a wrapper service for the implementation of MSAL-Angular auth_code flow + PKCE

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as Msal from '@azure/msal-browser'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MsalAuthService {

  private myMSALObj: Msal.PublicClientApplication;
  private account: Msal.AccountInfo;
  private loginRedirectRequest: Msal.RedirectRequest;
  private loginRequest: Msal.PopupRequest;
  private profileRedirectRequest: Msal.RedirectRequest;
  private profileRequest: Msal.PopupRequest;
  private mailRedirectRequest: Msal.RedirectRequest;
  private mailRequest: Msal.PopupRequest;
  private silentProfileRequest: Msal.SilentRequest;
  private silentMailRequest: Msal.SilentRequest;
  private silentLoginRequest: Msal.SsoSilentRequest;

  msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: '<App registration ID in Azure>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'
    }
  };

  msalInstance = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(this.msalConfig);

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.myMSALObj = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(this.msalConfig);
    this.account = null;
    this.setRequestObjects()
  }

  private setRequestObjects(): void {
    this.loginRequest = {
        scopes: []
    };

    this.loginRedirectRequest = {
      // ES6 feature that is spread operator and rest operator
        ...this.loginRequest,
        redirectStartPage: this.router.url
    };

    this.profileRequest = {
        scopes: ["User.Read"]
    };

    this.profileRedirectRequest = {
        ...this.profileRequest,
        redirectStartPage: this.router.url
    };

    // Add here scopes for access token to be used at MS Graph API endpoints.
    this.mailRequest = {
        scopes: ["Mail.Read"]
    };

    this.mailRedirectRequest = {
        ...this.mailRequest,
        redirectStartPage: this.router.url
    };

    this.silentProfileRequest = {
        scopes: ["openid", "profile", "User.Read", "User.Read.All"],
        account: null,
        forceRefresh: false
    };

    this.silentMailRequest = {
        scopes: ["openid", "profile", "Mail.Read"],
        account: null,
        forceRefresh: false
    };

    this.silentLoginRequest = {
        loginHint: "me@domain.com"
    }
  }


  private getAccount(): Msal.AccountInfo {
    // need to call getAccount here
    const currentAccounts = this.myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();
    if (currentAccounts === null) {
        console.log("No accounts detected");
        return null;
    }

    if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
        // TODO: Add choose account code here
        console.log("Multiple accounts detected, need to add choose account code.");
        return currentAccounts[0];
    } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
        return currentAccounts[0];
    }
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether we are in the middle of a redirect and handles state accordingly. Only required for redirect flows.
   *
   */
  loadAuthModule(): void {
    this.myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise().then((resp: Msal.AuthenticationResult) => {
      this.handleResponse(resp);
    }).catch(console.error);
  }

  /**
   * Handles the response from a popup or redirect. If response is null, will check if we have any accounts and attempt to sign in.
   * @param response
   */
  handleResponse(response: Msal.AuthenticationResult) {
    if (response !== null) {
      this.account = response.account;
    } else {
      console.log('getting account: ' + this.getAccount());
      this.account = this.getAccount();
    }

    if (this.account) {
      console.log('Welcome Message: ');
      console.log(this.account);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Calls ssoSilent to attempt silent flow. If it fails due to interaction required error, it will prompt the user to login using popup.
   * @param request
   */
  attemptSsoSilent() {
    this.myMSALObj.ssoSilent(this.silentLoginRequest).then(() => {
        this.account = this.getAccount();
        console.log('Welcome Message: ' + this.account);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("Silent Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof Msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            this.login("loginPopup");
        }
    })
  }

  /**
   * Calls loginPopup or loginRedirect based on given signInType.
   * @param signInType
   */
  login(signInType: string): void {
    if (signInType === "loginPopup") {
      console.log('Login Request (popup): ' + this.loginRequest);
      this.myMSALObj.loginPopup(this.loginRequest).then((resp: Msal.AuthenticationResult) => {
        console.log('response 2: ' + resp);
        this.handleResponse(resp);
      }).catch(console.error);
    } else if (signInType === "loginRedirect") {
      console.log('Login Request (redirect): ');
      console.log(this.loginRedirectRequest);
      this.myMSALObj.loginRedirect(this.loginRedirectRequest);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Logs out of current account.
   */
  logout(): void {
    const logOutRequest: Msal.EndSessionRequest = {
        account: this.account
    };

    this.myMSALObj.logout(logOutRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the token to read user profile data from MS Graph silently, or falls back to interactive redirect.
   */
  async getProfileTokenRedirect(): Promise<string> {
    this.silentProfileRequest.account = this.account;
    return this.getTokenRedirect(this.silentProfileRequest, this.profileRedirectRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the token to read user profile data from MS Graph silently, or falls back to interactive popup.
   */
  async getProfileTokenPopup(): Promise<string> {
    this.silentProfileRequest.account = this.account;
    return this.getTokenPopup(this.silentProfileRequest, this.profileRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the token to read mail data from MS Graph silently, or falls back to interactive redirect.
   */
  async getMailTokenRedirect(): Promise<string> {
    this.silentMailRequest.account = this.account;
    return this.getTokenRedirect(this.silentMailRequest, this.mailRedirectRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the token to read mail data from MS Graph silently, or falls back to interactive popup.
   */
  async getMailTokenPopup(): Promise<string> {
    this.silentMailRequest.account = this.account;
    return this.getTokenPopup(this.silentMailRequest, this.mailRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Gets a token silently, or falls back to interactive popup.
   */
  private async getTokenPopup(silentRequest: Msal.SilentRequest, interactiveRequest: Msal.PopupRequest): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const response: Msal.AuthenticationResult = await this.myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
      return response.accessToken;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("silent token acquisition fails.");
      if (e instanceof Msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
          console.log("acquiring token using redirect");
          return this.myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(interactiveRequest).then((resp) => {
              return resp.accessToken;
          }).catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
              return null;
          });
      } else {
          console.error(e);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets a token silently, or falls back to interactive redirect.
   */
  private async getTokenRedirect(silentRequest: Msal.SilentRequest, interactiveRequest: Msal.RedirectRequest): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const response = await this.myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
      return response.accessToken;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("silent token acquisition fails.");
      if (e instanceof Msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
          console.log("acquiring token using redirect");
          this.myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(interactiveRequest).catch(console.error);
      } else {
          console.error(e);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The app that I registered on Azure has the following API Permissions
[image]

**The second service: msal-fetch.service.ts**
The purpose of it is just to get the response of the queried graph and return it to whatever component consumes that service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfo } from '../_models/user-info';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MsalFetchService {

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Makes an Authorization "Bearer"  request with the given accessToken to the given endpoint.
   * @param endpoint
   * @param accessToken
   */
  async callEndpointWithToken(endpoint: string, accessToken: string): Promise<UserInfo> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    console.log('request made at: ' + new Date().toString());

    const response = await fetch(endpoint, options);
    return (await response.json()) as UserInfo;
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to authenticate if the user is not authenticated.. then land on the home page which is http://localhost:4200

The main problem is when I go to my **app.component.ts** and try to call the following functions from my msalAuthService, it goes into infinite loop due to infinite redirects to http://localhost:4200

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GRAPH_CONFIG } from './_config/graph-config';
import { UserInfo } from './_models/user-info';
import { MsalAuthService } from './_services/msal-auth.service';
import { MsalFetchService } from './_services/msal-fetch.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private msalAuthService: MsalAuthService,
    private msalFetchService: MsalFetchService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msalAuthService.loadAuthModule();
    this.msalAuthService.login('loginRedirect');
    this.seeProfile();
  }

  async seeProfile(): Promise<void> {
    const token = await this.msalAuthService.getProfileTokenRedirect();
    if (token && token.length > 0) {
      const graphResponse: UserInfo = await this.msalFetchService.callEndpointWithToken(GRAPH_CONFIG.GRAPH_ME_ENDPT, token);
      console.log(graphResponse);
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.msalAuthService.logout();
  }
}
```

I can't figure out why the infinite redirects are happening when I am supposed to navigate to http://localhost:4200 and then get authenticated with office 365 login (if not authenticated) otherwise gets redirected back to http://localhost:4200 where I can see my profile in the console window.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msalAuthService.loadAuthModule();

    // if you redirect back to same page, this will fire again
    this.msalAuthService.login('loginRedirect');

    this.seeProfile();
  }
```

I think that's your problem. It'll keep firing. I was just in the middle of dealing with a similar issue while testing the new @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 alpha build. You can try one of these:

1. create a login button instead of auto login
2. redirect to a different route in your app
3. set a temporary cookie that checks if login is in progress

This is how I'm handling it.  Keep in mind this is using msal-angular v2 alpha, but it seems mature enough.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkAccount();
    var mycookie = this.getCookie("inprogress");
    if(!this.loggedIn && mycookie != "inprogress"){
      this.setCookie("inprogress", "inprogress", 1);
      this.doLogin();
    }
    else
    {
      this.eraseCookie("inprogress");
    }
  }
  
  checkAccount() {
    this.loggedIn = this.msal.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }
  
  doLogin() {
     this.msal
      .loginRedirect({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest })
      .subscribe((r) => {
        console.log(r);
        this.eraseCookie('inprogress');
      });
  }
  
  setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var expires = 'expires=' + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';' + expires + ';path=/';
  }

  getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + '=';
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  checkCookie() {
    var user = this.getCookie('username');
    if (user != '') {
      alert('Welcome again ' + user);
    } else {
      user = prompt('Please enter your name:', '');
      if (user != '' && user != null) {
        this.setCookie('username', user, 365);
      }
    }
  }
  
  eraseCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; Max-Age=-99999999;';
  }
```